# Expression of the dipole moment vector in spherical coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, coordinate-systems

In this problem:

[image]

[image]

The z axis is rotated such that $p_{i}$ lies in the origin and points in the $ \hat z$ direction, so we can use the formula

[image]
which works in this specific coordinate system.

My question is how to express $p$ as a vector now in this coordinate system? I think after the rotation of the  z-axis, now the $p$ vector makes an angle of $ 2 \theta$ with the new z axis, so I think I can project that vector on the $z$ and $y$ axes to get:

$ \vec p = p ( \cos(2 \theta) \hat z + \sin( 2 \theta) \hat y ) $

And I want to use this matrix to transform the cartesian unit vectors into the spherical ones,

[image]

But the book claims that $\vec p$ is expressed as:

$$ \vec p = p \cos(\theta) \hat r + p \sin(\theta) \hat \theta$$

How to reach that conclusion?

Comment: is $E_{i}$ the electric field due to dipole $p_{i}$ on $p$?

Comment: Yes, Electric field due to pi at the point $(r, \theta)$ where p is